# Base Programming for vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, xss, sql-injection, mysql, sql-server

Hello, I am a beginner looking for some information.

My question is the following:  In order to understand certain security concepts is it essential that I understand the underlying languages?

For example, to understand XSS should I know Javascript?  To understand SQL Injection should I know SQL?  Or is it enough to have a background in programming and study vulnerabilities that use technologies that I am not particularly familiar with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be very difficult to truly understand security concepts like XSS and SQLi without knowing at least a little about the underlying languages.  While you may be able to execute a XSS or SQLi attack without knowing javascript or SQL, it would make you more of a script kiddy than it would a true security expert.

It also truly limits your ability to find vulnerabilities that are a little off the beaten path.  The deeper your understanding of how a language works the easier it will be for you to exploit applications that use it.

That being said, knowing a little about a language will go a long way.  You don't need to be a SQL master to understand how SQLi works.  Just being familiar with the basics will help you familiarize yourself with concepts like SQLi.

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much, you took almost five months of doubts of my life, and helped me a lot in a few words. Thank you!